# jQuery to enable and disable textbox with button on click

Tags: jquery

When I click the button the first time, I would like textbox1 to be enabled, but textbox2 and textbox3 disabled, then when I click the button for the second time, textbox2 is enabled and textbox11 & textbox3 are disabled, and lastly when I click the button for the third time, textbox3 is enabled and textbox1 and textbox2 are disabled. Please help me.. Thank you

I have tried this, I need a jQuery script of this body:

```
<input type="text" name="text1" id="txt">
<input type="text" name="text2" id="txt2">
<input type="text" name="text3" id="txt3">
<input type="button" value="edit" name="button1" id="btn">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say like bellow

```
var count = 0;

$('#btn').click(function(){
    count = count%3;
    $('input[type="text"').attr('disabled',true).eq(count++).attr('disabled',false);
})
```

On fourth click it will again enable first input.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/65/)

Comment: Thankyou dear, but can't running:(

Comment: Okey, thankyou but can this work if i put in notepad++?

Comment: @RachmaSasqia there could be problems of how are you putting jquery & all, see here http://pastebin.com/6Rbc9pQQ, paste this contents in notepad++.

Comment: Elegant solution, not for a noob but elegant :)